# X-Robots noindex all wordpress URLs in specific subdirectory

Tags: .htaccess, subdirectory, noindex, x-robots-tag

I want to noindex all websites/URLs in the subdirectory "author".

Examples:

```
example.com/author/torben
example.com/author/lucy
example.com/author/*
```

**.htaccess** seems to be the right place to do it.

I found some code that should do the trick but does not

```
<If "%{REQUEST_URI} =~ m#^/author/#">
Header set X-Robots-Tag "noindex"
</If>
```

Something is wrong

```
curl -I https://www.example.com/author/torben
```

does not show a noindex.

What am I doing wrong?
Thanks for you help. It is much appreciated

**EDIT:**

I searched and found something that can do the trick

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
   <If "%{THE_REQUEST} =~ m#/author/?#">
    Header set X-Robots-Tag "noindex"
   </If>
</IfModule>
```